# How can I generate a random string, out of a pre prepared list of strings in C#?

Tags: c#, list, random

I need to generate a random string from a pool of 6 pre-generated strings.
I created a list, but I don't understand how to use "random" to generate one random string out of that list.

This is what I have so far:

```
string RandomPowerSentence()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
  
    List<string> powerStrings = new List<string>()
    {
        "You are kind!",
        "You are beautiful!",
        "You are smart!"
    };

    //I assume that here I put the code that generates a random string out of the list with rnd
    

    return  "the random string from the list";
```

Help will be very appreciated!

I used the random class, but I don't understand/know how to use it with strings and not ints.

Comment: get a random number in the range of 0 - `powerStrings.Count - 1` then use that number as an index for the `powerStrings` list.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts.
 i recommend taking the [Tour], as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution:

```
string RandomPowerSentence()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    int myRandomNumber;

    List<string> powerStrings = new List<string>()
    {
        "You are kind!",
        "You are beautiful!",
        "You are smart!",
        "You are awesome!",
        "You are funny!",
        "You're a f*cking A!"
    };

    // rnd.Next(int, int)   Returns a positive random integer within the specified minimum and maximum range (includes min and excludes max).
    myRandomNumber = rnd.Next(0, powerStrings.Count);

    return powerStrings[myRandomNumber];
}
```

An explanation of the usage of "Random()": https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/generate-random-numbers-in-csharp

An explanation of the usage of "Count": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=net-7.0

Comment: Mind that you should not create a new `Random` instance on each method call. Use at least a class-scoped one.